# SWING text editor with basic functionality

Tags: swing, text-editor

***The story behind:***

I'm a lazy ass.

***What I need:***

I'm writing my thesis/disseration (I don't know how do you call it in english right now, and since I'm a lazy ass, I shall not check). Could you please tell me if there is around a **basic** SWING Text Editor? Something like the SWT Text Editor in the Eclipse Plugin Examples?
I need to implement on top of that a syntax highlighter but I would like to get the basic functionality already done (like "open files" or "copy/paste").

I need a SWING basic text editor because this would be a component of an application already written with SWING and I'm not really proficient in it.

My goal would be open file, save file, copy, paste, cut.

So far I've found this: http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=2175&lngWId=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the starting point for you: 
[Swing Tutorial: Using Text Components](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)

HINT: use JTextPane or JEditorPane, depending on your needs.